# My App reads txt files even if they are deleted

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have developed an app that reads some data from a txt file.

```
jQuery.get('/mnt/sdcard/koinoxrista/File.txt',
   function(data){
      //do something
   }
```

The strange thing is that since yesterday, even if I delete the txt file, my app still reads it...

The problem does not exist if I remove and reinstall my app.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable cache ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/mnt/sdcard/koinoxrista/File.txt',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in your app's cache memory every time you execute `jQuery.get`